# How to create a macro in word to import multiple tables from excel?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Frequently in my job I need to generate reports with lots of tables of inputs and results. Especially for the result tables, one change in analysis may require editing a dozen spreadsheets. I'd like to create a macro in word that pulls in data from a spreadsheet, with each table on it's own tab, so that if I update any of those tables in excel the word document tables will also update. Given the number of tables/data points, I don't want to have to tell the macro to pull each single data point. The aim would be to reduce time and errors from manual entry.

I'm thinking this would involve the following steps, but not sure how to go about them:
1) Define the name/size for each table in word with matching name/size in excel
2) Tell the macro to pull the data into a table format

I'm not sure if this is possible as so far I've only seen how to insert a caption or a text box, not insert or update entire tables. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by googling your question. You will find existing code that you might use. You will also find problems you didn't yet think about, and their solutions. Come back here when you have something that almost works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you may not even need any VBA code.

If you copy a range from Excel and paste it into Word using Paste Special with the 'paste link' option, any subsequent changes in the Excel range will automatically be reflected in the document when the workbook is saved. And, if you name the range in Excel before copying/pasting, the Word content will expend/contract to reflect changes in the named range's scope in Excel. A variety of paste formats is supported.

Alternatively, you might use a DATABASE field in Word.